# Error occurred during report processing. Report server is unable to access encrypted data. Apply backup key or delete all encrypted content

Tags: 2013, migration, reporting-services

I have migrated the SQL Server Reporting Sevices from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. I followed [Migrating SharePoint 2010 Reporting Services To SharePoint 2013](http://microscoff.com/2014/05/20/migrating-sharepoint-2010-reporting-services-sharepoint-2013/) to migrate SQL Server Reporting Services and now I see this below Error when I open the Report (.rdl).

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted).
>   The report server is unable to access encrypted data. Apply a back-up
>   key or delete all encrypted content. (rsEncryptedDataUnavailable)

**To summarize the steps that I performed based on article:**

> - Create SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application
> - Backup "Report Server DB", "Report Server Temp DB" and Encryption keys
> - Restore the Encryption Keys and Databases
> - Mount "Report Server DB" to the Service application
> - Remove default Report Server Temp DB created while creating Service application
> - Enable SSRS Service connections to a web application.
> - Copy the configurations files from Source to target(Rsreportserver.config, Rssvrpolicy.config, Web.config)

Answer (score 0):

The process should be this:

SharePoint 2010:

- Backup SSRS encryption key
- Backup the SSRS databases (including Temp if using SQL 2012)

SharePoint 2013:

- Restore SSRS databases to SQL
- Create new SSRS SA specifying the existing SSRS database name (this will cause it to upgrade the database)
- Import your encryption key to the SSRS SA (Central Admin -> Manage Service Applications -> SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application -> Encryption Key)

That should allow you to keep your secrets.

Comment: Hi Trevor, Thanks for the response. I have followed the order that you have recommended and still seeing the same error when accessing the report. To add more details, I am using report server in "Native" mode and also have shared data sources/data connections.

Comment: If you're using SSRS in Native mode, then you need to repost in Server Fault as it is unrelated to SharePoint.